# How to Add Password Control to Open Folder

Tags: finder, password, encryption

I'd like to add protection to a folder on my computer (OSX El Capitan) where it requires a password for a user to open it in finder. I've tried googling this and all the answers seem to involve creating on an encrypted disk image which isn't what I'd like to accomplish.

I'm concerned less with encrypting sensitive data than with adding a cheap layer of protection to a folder so that it would be harder for someone to accidentally open if they were browsing around looking for a file. Just want something that asks for a password when the folder is clicked on in finder.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can you clarify whether we're talking about a shared computer with one (or maybe a *shared*) user account? In other words, what you *want* to do is prevent yourself (and anyone else accessing the computer from your account) from accidentally opening the folder?

Comment: It is a personal computer, my account is the only one that ever gets used. I work as a programmer though, so sometimes my coworkers will use my machine. Just want to have a simple way to make sure they don't accidentally open private / nsfw stuff. So yes, adding password control to open a folder on my account.